# How do i use the value of variable X

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
docRef.update({

            sequencenumber: {
                x: false
              }

         })
```

In this case consider the value

> x=3

I want the field value to be

> 3:false

But in my database the field value is

> x:false

Comment: Do you mean sequencenumber[x]=false or ES6: `[x]:false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer:

1. use ES2015+ [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names): `[x]:false`
2. Use bracket notation:
   `obj.sequencenumber[x]=false;`

```js
var x = 3

// ES2015+: 
obj = {
  sequencenumber: {
    [x]: false // 
  }
}
console.log(obj)


// previous versions:

var obj = {
  sequencenumber: {}
}
obj.sequencenumber[x] = false; // bracket notation
console.log(obj)

// To read it:

console.log(obj.sequencenumber[3]) 
// or 
console.log(obj.sequencenumber[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

In ES6 use like `[variable]`.

```js
var x=3;
var a = {
  sequencenumber: {
    [x]: false
  }
}

console.log(a)
```

Comment: no do like this `doc.get(sequencenumber[x]);`. or else its not working show me the working fiddle

Comment: **UPDATED FIDDLE**:  i dont know what is the exact result from `doc.get` .Try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/prasanth1036/3ne5ogc2/6/

Comment: Perhape `doc.get().sequencenumber[x] == true`

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript's bracket notation for objects however you will have to initialise your data object `sequencenumber` before you can edit it. See bellow:

```
sequencenumber = {};
sequencenumber[x] = true;
docRef.update(sequencenumber);
```